# Invisible text in Intellij IDEA

Tags: fonts, intellij-idea, intellij-13

So basically I moved with my .IntellijIdea13 directory to new system (from Ubuntu to Arch), run IDE only once on new system and it worked ok if I remember correctly. However after some customization of the new system (installed new fonts, changed default terminal font... I don't know if this is related but who knows), I run Intellij and it looks like this:

[image]

Text is invisible, with few exceptions that are probably not actual fonts but some images I guess. Any ideas how can I fix this? I pretty much cannot navigate through menus, but maybe I can change something in config files in .IntellijIdea13? Any suggestions?

**Added #1:**
This seems to be unrelated to IDEA settings, as even when I remove .IntellijIdea13 directory - the problem persists. So it is something wrong with java?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.0) (Arch Linux build 7.u60_2.5.0-2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138376/why-all-the-text-is-invisible-in-intellij

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the same problem, can be flagged as duplicate :) .

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Project Settings >> Appearance >>

Check for the options of theme , that may help you back with the original color and make things visiable

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu XFCE (IntelliJ 2017.3, Dracula theme) I tried various things but found overriding the default font did the job...

Go to: File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Override default fonts by (not recommended): DejaVu Sans
Restart IntelliJ